# Can not create react app via the command prompt

Tags: node.js, reactjs, command-line, create-react-app

Can anyone help with the following errors? I'm trying to setup the react folder. I have node.js installed.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: From the error, it seems like your package.json is empty or it's missing.

Comment: @HardikModha I can see that, but shouldn't this be downloaded automatically?

Comment: Have you tried running `npm cache clean`? Then try `create-react-app`.

Comment: @HardikModha doing it...

Comment: @HardikModha THAT WORKED!, please post it as an answer, I've  tried everything else but didn't work!

Comment: Sure..Will post it.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try running `npm cache clean`, that would solve the error. When you've tried everything and nothing seems to work, you can try clearing your npm cache and most of the time it works. :)